# Where to find the translated OData query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to know where is the translated OData query when I hit for example `http://www.com/api/product?$filter=Id%20eq%206`.
OData query translate these query to SQL code or query expression or something else?

Actually, I want to know the Life Cycle of OData.

Comment: Ruffly: HTTP->OData(Parse to Expression tree) -> Entity Framework(Gen SQL from exp) -> SQL EXECUTE -> Entity Framework (Map to entity) -> OData (Serialize for OData) -> HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter of type `System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions` to the Get() method on your controller. It will give you a strongly-typed object model for most query options, including `$filter`. See [Supporting OData Query Options in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) for details.